# Magento 2 - Not allow to add same product into cart

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart

We are developing a custom module for not allowing user to add the same product (same SKU) into the cart. In the official documentation, I cannot find any information about it. Which class I should override to achieve this?

Comment: So, the customer can add only a product with qty 1?

Comment: Yes. If the customer add the same product twice, we want to show an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the setting in Admin Panel.

Goto Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart, set the value to 1

[image]

Thanks @Khoa

Answer (score 0):

We can set the **Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** per product:

--*Magento version 2.0.7*

[image]

--*Magento version 2.1*:

Choose product > **Advanced Inventory**:

[image]

Comment: I don't see this setting v2.0.8. Is it only available for v2.1? how to do it in v2.0.8?

Comment: I have just updated my answer.

Comment: I don't see this setting in my v2.0.8. I'm using Community Edition.

Comment: https://s15.postimg.org/f2jankf6z/Screen_Shot_2016_09_02_at_23_33_28.png

Comment: Strange to say! I'm also using CE version. You should search `Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart` in your source code.

Comment: You can check with a fresh version.